# Passing format string to a directive and interpolating it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a format string to a directive and make the directive interpolate it with an object. The problem is that if I use curly brackets Angular tries to interpolate the string before the directive is even created. If I escape the curly brackets, Angular isn't showing the values of the object (the string isn't interpolated correctly).

How can I pass a format string to a directive?

This is my demo code template:

```
<div test-directive item-text="{{ x }} - {{ y }}"></div>
```

Angular app/directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["test-directive"]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});


var dir = angular.module('test-directive', []);

dir.directive("testDirective", ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {

    template: "<div>{{ text }}</div>",

    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      var obj = {
        x: 6,
        y: 9
      };
      $scope.text = $interpolate(attrs.itemText)( obj );
    }
  }
}]);
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vUVVuLVBptEmUcv3y7o4?p=preview

Edit:

Applying @Lucas's annswer to my original problem isn't solving the issue. For some reason the attr gets wiped, even if I'm not erasing it anywhere.

Please check the line 301: http://plnkr.co/edit/6bjW35D3W1dTGQz9kNSn?p=preview

Note that `itemLabel` isn't changed anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to change it as

```
$scope.text = $interpolate(element.attr(attrs.$attr.itemText))( obj );
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ctPalH7Szqqnpit5t0On?p=preview

Comment: This works fine in my demo, but it's returning an empty string in my library. Can you think about anything that would cause that?

Comment: This is probably because `element.attr(xyz)` changes as a result of interpolation, so timing is crucial.

Comment: @ExpertSystem So I need to get the value of the attr before the link funciton kicks in. How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on the exact implementation of your directive. All things considered, just defining a helper function that replaces the symbols and interpolates seems the best approach ("best" as in "simplest", "cleanest", "no-surprises").

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the actual usecase is, but from your example, you don't seem to need interpolation (so you shouldn't use it and avoid the overhead).
What you (seem to) need, is to evaluate a expression in some context (e.g. `obj`).
One way of doing it, is to use [Scope's `$eval()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval); e.g.:

```
<div test-directive item-text="x+' - '+y" ...

...
link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
  var obj = {x: 6, y: 9};
  scope.text = scope.$eval(attrs.itemText, obl);
}
```

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fh94rRhNF8ihA1ErdYJE?p=preview)

---

**EDIT:** Admitedly, this beats the purpose of simplicity, so here is another approach using a helper service that replaces the start-/end-symbols and interpolates: [Demo](http://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/BNRMLw?editors=101)

Comment: No, this isn't about evaluating math operations, but about rendering the actual items.

Comment: Not sure what _"rendering the actual items"_ means, but `$eval()` is not about evaluating math operations; it's about evaluating Angular expression (it is internally using the `$parse` service, which is also what `$interplate` is using). So, in your case, the expression would need to be `x + ' - ' + y`. I updated the answer to do what you want, I understand this kind of beats the purpose of using `{{...}}` for simplicity.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be useful because the format can contain complex formats, like `This is the icon {{icon}} of the item with id {{id}} and name '{{name}}'`. That same format but suitable for `eval` would look kind of awkward, imho. `'This is the icon ' + icon + ' of the item with id' + id + ' and name \'' + name + '\''`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "beats the purpose of using `{{...}}` for simplicity. All things considered, I believe replacing the symbols is the best approach (e.g. using a helper function, helper service, even decorating/augmenting `$interpolate`). See my updated answer for a demo.